# Is there a (C/C++) library of for bit twiddling?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, libraries

There are many known bit twiddling hacks, e.g. the list [here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html); as well as [numerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573751/bit-twiddling-for-checking-whether-a-number-is-in-particular-range) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092659/c-bit-counting-similar-to-bit-twiddling-hack) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549303/i-need-help-on-bit-twiddling) on SO.

Is there a standard-ish library, or even a single header file, implementing all of these? (I would get, as inline functions and/or as preprocessor macros.)

**Edit:** I'm not interested in implementations using specialized types, i.e. bit vectors or bit sets, but rather code which works directly on your ints/unsigneds/etc.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I didn't ask for a recommendation, merely for references.

Comment: Not that I know of. There's a ton of them anyway, with endless variations, so it's not even feasible. http://programming.sirrida.de/ has source with a lot in it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's std `<bitset>` or even [bitmagic](http://bmagic.sourceforge.net/)

Googling will find even more

Answer (score 1):

These are 2 libraries named "Bitfile" library and "Bitarray" library. You can find it at:

http://michael.dipperstein.com/bitlibs/

There is also a single header file which you might find useful at:

http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bit-hacks-header-file/